# How to use an NgRx select as Subject instead of BehaviorSubject

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

Is there a way to treat an NgRx select as a `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`?

I don't want to execute the next when the subscription is made the first time *(default behavior)*. Instead, a want to execute it just when the state is changed.

```
this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.selectErrorMessage)).subscribe((message) => {
      /* This content is executed the first time the subscription is made, 
         and after that is executed everytime the state change */
      this.isLoading = false;     
      this.errorMessage = { ...message };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.store.pipe(select(fromAuth.selectErrorMessage)).pipe(skip(1))`

will ignore the current value and only emit the next value.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to execute it the first time even if I have a valid message. I only want to execute it when the message change in the store. I know this can be done using an Observable of type Subject, but NgRx seems to use BehaviorSubject by default.

Comment: What about just use `.pipe(skip(1))` so it ignores the current one and only takes the next emit?